# Tensorflow Custom TFLite java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot allocate memory for the interpreter

Tags: android, python, tensorflow

I have created a custom tensorflow lite model using retrain.py from https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py using the following command

```
python retrain.py --image_dir newImageDirectory --tfhub_module https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/mobilenet_v2_100_224/feature_vector/1
```

Then I convert using `toco` the `output_graph.pb` file to a lite file. Using the below command:

```
bazel run tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco:toco -- --input_file=/tmp/output_graph.pb --output_file=/tmp/optimized.lite --input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF --output_format=TFLITE --inpute_shape=1,224,224,3 --input_array=input --output_array=final_result --inference_type=FLOAT --input_data_type=FLOAT
```

Then I take the new lite file and the labels.txt file and put them in tensorflow for poets 2 https://github.com/googlecodelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2 to see if I can have it start to classify new categories. When the application launches I receive the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Can not allocate memory for the interpreter                                                                                            at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.createInterpreter(Native Method)
                                                                      at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.<init>(NativeInterpreterWrapper.java:63)
                                                                                        at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.<init>(NativeInterpreterWrapper.java:51)
                                                                                        at org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.<init>(Interpreter.java:90)
                                                                                        at com.example.android.tflitecamerademo.ImageClassifier.<init>(ImageClassifier.java:97)
```

Comment: I've been running into this issue when trying to use a retrained InceptionV3 model, I thought it was caused by the model size (about 80 MB), but it must be something else when this error occurs even with these smaller MobileNet models.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: This problem has been reported here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19982

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the computer you are using, make sure you have enough ram to allocate for the program, or try increasing your swap file size?